# SignalR Refused to connect to [url] because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: javascript, .net, signalr, content-security-policy, wss

I've created a SignalR project in .NET 4.8.

I was using signalR correctly as described in the documentation. My two script tags:

```html
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://mySignalRServer/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

I'm initializing the connection in the following way:

```js
$.connection.hub.url = "https://mySignalRServer/signalr";
let screencasting = $.connection.screencastingHub;

$.connection.hub.qs = 'uuid=' + masterGuid + '&master=true';
$.connection.hub.logging = true;
screencasting.client.changeTransport = changeTransport;

$.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'webSockets' }).done(function () {
    console.log('---Connected to signalR server via WebSockets');
});
```

When the code hits the following line `$.connection.hub.start()` the following error occurs:

[image]

> jquery.signalR-2.4.1.js:1871 Refused to connect to
>   'wss://mySignalRServer/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=2.1&uuid=56b12321-1091-48aa-b52f-dc1407b3804a&master=true&connectionToken=WOP95HhCwdN7ogruYHpfrrsZofenOqo5kRDVLJh6S6zUH0AN74cUTEL44qORGBCRMWiGH5ei12826qLB%2BMHFa7YqaN1KeIYmG7dUaE%2B6DiF2CIwaNTl4dwbwR6t3Cxgx&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22screencastinghub%22%7D%5D&tid=8'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "connect-src https:".

Interestingly enough, this code was working fine. Could it be a sertificate error? How can I add this `Content Security Policy (CSP)`. ([enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP))

Is it added as header somewhere? In the html head?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of tests, this is the solution that worked out for me:

In `Web.config` file I've added the following line:

```xml
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src https:; connect-src https: wss:" />
      </customHeaders>
</<httpProtocol>
```

For more information, check [this](https://content-security-policy.com/) and [that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) out.